# Tool to send files to an iPad2 from Win 7/8 computers

Tags: windows, gratis, file-management, ios, ipad-app

What gratis tool can I use to send huge files from my desktop computer to my iPad? Files can be .avi video I want to see later on my tablet, or .zip archive I just want to store on my iPad.

I don't want to use iTunes. For the moment I use my Dropbox account to download the videos with the *favorite* option, but I'm space limited.

Comment: Probably your best option might be an SD card.

Answer (score 3):

I use [FileZilla FTP server](https://filezilla-project.org/) on Windows + some FTP client on my iPad:

- free
- no size limit
- with habit takes less than 1 minute to set up

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest [BitTorrent Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync).

It is a peer-to-peer sync tool, as easy to use as Dropbox, but not limited in space.

Your files will fly directly across your local network (or the Internet) without being stored anywhere online.

Free, available for most platforms including yours.